# How do I do this in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Im currently evaluating Drupal to see if we can use it to replace our framework. My problem is I have this legacy tables which I would want to try to reflect in Drupal. It involves a join table. There's quite a lot of this kind of relationship in our existing web app so I am looking for possible ways to solve it.
[image]

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: have you checked CCK + Views? with views you can build really complex relationship

Comment: Answers below are right for implementation. Once you have your content structure right, you'll probably want to look at the 'tablewizard' and 'migrate' modules. They require a little coding but make it very easy to get content into drupal.

Comment: I think I need to study more how drupal relates tables to each other. One of my worries is that if I put all Projects,COmpanies,and other stuff into nodes, with each one is its own content-type. Having records greater 7K-15K in some tables, Im a bit concern how drupal will handle these large amount of data. I'll have to dig deeper. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, and it's hard to know which is best with no context about what you're actually doing with the data, but here are some options:

One way to do this is to make a content type representing each table (using [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck)) with the foreign keys represented by type-specific node reference fields. Doing everything as nodes gives you a bunch of prebuilt functionality around nodes, but has a bit of overhead you may want to avoid.

Another option is to leave your database just like it is now. Drupal can do direct database queries, or you can use [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) to expose your tables to Views.

Another option, if those referenced tables really only have 1 non-ID field, is to do the project_companies_assignments as nodes and do the other 3 as taxonomies. But this won't work if those are really more complex entities, and wouldn't be very flexible if they might become more complex.

Comment: When you say potential overhead ,does this mean storing everything as nodes will slow down my site?is this because drupal has to do several self joins?In reality the projects table has 15,000 records  ,8000 for companies and around 44000 for the roles table.

Comment: Mostly implementation overhead.

Comment: The overhead of nodes is directly tied to the benefits: most modules in Drupal interact with nodes, so every time you do something with a node (load it, save it, view it), most modules you have installed are checking if they need to do something, and possibly actually doing something based on what you just did. Where that something is useful, nodes are useful. Where it's not, this is all overhead.

Answer (score 1):

What about using hook_views_api and exposing your legacy tables in hook_views_data? i tried something like this myself - not sure if that is what you want...

try and let me know if that works for you.

http://drupalwalla.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-do-you-expose-your-legacy-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Going with Views and CCK, optionally with the additional Data module has one huge disadvantage: it comes with complexity.

My preferred alternative, is to write your own module. Drupal offers little help wrt database abstraction, it comes not with a proper ORM or such. But with some simple CRUD functions for the data in the database, a few simple forms in front, and a menu-callback with some pages to present the data, you can -quite often- get your datamodel worked out much faster then going the route of the overly complex, often poorly documented CCK and views modules. KISS.